# Promise that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have nested promise where a function calls another function and both return promises. Function `b` is calling function `a` and when the promise of the function `a` is done function `b` resolves its own deferred and passing the result from `a` and its own result.

```
function a(){
  var d =  $.Deferred();
  makeSomeAsyncCall(function(){
    d.resolve('a')
  })
  return d.promise();
}

function b(){
  var d =  $.Deferred();
  a= a()

  a.done(function(a){d.resolve(a, 'b')})
   .fail(function(a){d.reject(a, 'b')})

  return d.promise();

}

b().done(function(a, b){console.log(a, b)})
 .fail(function(a, b){console.log(a, b)})
```

I wonder if there is way to wright this without creating a deferred in function `b`

Comment: What is the purpose of `b`? why can't `b` just return `a` directly? I think you over-simplified your example, to the point where it can be simplified more so than you probably want. `a().done(function(a){console.log(arguments)}).fail(function(a){console.log(arguments)})`

Comment: The point is that `b` has to add its own parameter to the resolved deferred. So that the initial call can log `"a"` and `"b"`. I cant see a way to do this without the second deferred in function `b`

Comment: Then the answer is no, in one form or another you'll have to create a new deferred object if you want to add parameters to it. It could be done with .then possibly, but i don't think it would be much cleaner in this case (and would still require creating a new deferred object.)

Comment: Seems strange, you're resolving the promise in `b()` at the same time as the promise in `a()` is resolved, which pretty much means you don't really need a promise at all in `b()`, just return the values -> http://jsfiddle.net/SHd8f/

Comment: As described in my first comment, both functions have to return an argument that needs to end in the final `done` / `fail` methods.

Comment: That's great, and you are of course doing something asynchronous in both functions that doesn't already return a built in promise etc. otherwise you're just reinventing the wheel, and unless both functions are async, there's no need for promises ?

Comment: No, only function `a` make some async stuff, but `b` needs to return something that let me log `"a"` and `"b"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if there is way to wright this without creating a deferred in function b

Yes, there is. To chain two (potentially asynchronous) functions is the sole purpose of the main [promise](http://promisesaplus.com/) method,[**`then`**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (in old versions known as `pipe`). Simply write

```
function b() {
    return a().then(function success(aresult) {
        return [aresult, "b"];
    }, function error(aerror) {
        return $.Deferred().reject(aerror, "b");
    });
}
```

I'm not sure whether you actually need that `error` handler, if you don't specify it then the `aerror` will be propagated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if there is way to wright this without creating a deferred in
>   function b

No, I don't believe there is.  If `a` manages resolving its own deferred, and `b` wants to return a deferred that get's *two* result values, one of which is the result of `a`, then you must instantiate a new deferred within `b`.

However, it would be interesting to know exactly why you are structuring it like this given that in your example processing within `b()` ignores the result of `a()`.  You may want to consider creating deferred results for `a` and `b` completely independent of one another then joining them when you invoke them instead of nesting the calls.  Using $.when():

```
$.when(a(), b()).done(function(a,b) {
    // process both results
}).fail(function(a,b) {
    // process both results
});
```

Written this way `b()` doesn't need to know anything about `a()`.